# MongoDB 'root' user creation in Windows

Tags: mongodb

On Linux machine, I have created user as follows:

```
db.createUser({ user : "admin", pwd : "admin", roles : [{role: "root", db: "admin"}]});
```

I want to create a similar user in windows,but since we don't have `"root"` in Windows machine, which role is equivalent to `"root"`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The equivalent of root in windows would be administrator

But the mongodb shell commands in windows/linux are the same. Also the user roles are the same between the systems since you are working with mongodb and not the operating system. So just make sure to use the same mongodb version.

To find out what roles are available (in mongodb v3.2), you can do a db.getRoles() request:
https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.2/reference/method/db.getRoles/

Comment: I  ran the same command and able to create a user with "root" role in windows. i logged to mongo with mongo -u admin -p admin admin command. .I am trying to create a db using command "create db aligneconfig" but i am getting exception related to syntax error.I have to create another app user " db.createUser({ user : "aligneadmin", pwd : "aligneadmin", roles : [{role: "root", db: "aligneconfig"}]});".I have used the command "set" as well and o/p shows switched to "alignecongid", but when i run  cmd to create a new user it throws exception "rror: couldn't add user:No role named root@aligneconfig

Comment: I am using version: MongoDB shell version v3.4.5

Comment: use the command

**use aligneconfig** -> this switches to the db (you don't have to create it)

and then use a normal db.insert()

Comment: and if you want to create a new user that doesn't have the root role, then you need to assert a different role.
https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.createUser/

Your question is not very clear about what exactly you want to do and what your problem is